# Embedded font style not working on mobile

Tags: css, fonts

I am developing a responsive web application. I encountered a problem that the font family doesn't work as expected on mobile, but it works as expected on a computer. Why is this the case?

Code:

**HTML**

```
  <link href="css/fonts/fonts.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'uni_sans_regularregular';
src: url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.svg#uni_sans_regularregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_lightregular';
    src: url('uni-sans-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('uni-sans-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.svg#uni_sans_lightregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_bold_italicitalic';
    src: url('uni-sans-bolditalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('uni-sans-bolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('uni-sans-bolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('uni-sans-bolditalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('uni-sans-bolditalic-webfont.svg#uni_sans_bold_italicitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_boldregular';
    src: url('uni-sans-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('uni-sans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('uni-sans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('uni-sans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('uni-sans-bold-webfont.svg#uni_sans_boldregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_lightregular';
    src: url('uni-sans-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('uni-sans-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('uni-sans-light-webfont.svg#uni_sans_lightregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_thinregular';

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which platform? ios, android, windows mobile, blackberry?

Comment: ios, android, windows mobile, blackberry

Comment: Strip it down to 1 font declaration with just the SVG and WOFF files and see if you can get that to work on mobile.  If it continues to not display then I'd assume your probably defining it wrong in the CSS, or your font files are corrupt, or you just have a crappy connection and the files aren't downloading on your phone, or for the SVG declaration, the name after the hashtag may not be correct (it should match what it is defined as in the svg code.. sometimes people think it's random like defining the font-family name.  And that last font-face declaration.. what's that? syntax error or typo

Comment: can you please give me a sample code or could you edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

First, open your SVG file with a text editor and find out if the name you've written in the hashtag for the SVG matches what it says in the file.

If it matches, try this, if not, adjust accordingly.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sans_regular';
    src: url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.svg#uni_sans_regularregular') format('svg');
    src: url('uni-sans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family:'uni_sans_regular',Arial,sans-serif; }
```

If the font still doesn't display on mobile then I'd assume your SVG or WOFF font files are corrupt, the path to the font file is not correct, or the files aren't downloading to the mobile device for some other reason (slow connection perhaps).

---

The SVG file should work for Firefox 3.5, Chrome 0.3, Safari 3.1, Opera 9, and all iOS devices.  The TTF file will pick up IE9 and Android 2.2.  You don't need the EOT file unless you want to cover IE8-.  I just reduced it to the minimum number of includes so you can narrow down the issue.

---

If your hosting the file on an IIS server, you may need to adjust your server settings.  IIS will not serve files with unknown MIME types so you must set the MIME type for SVG to image/svg+xml, similarly for WOFF.  [Instructions from Microsoft (link)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx)

---

If your testing with a 3rd party browser app on your mobile device, try testing on the default browser that comes with the device because many 3rd party apps have their own quirks.